# How to run and access Blockchain.info platform on a remote server?

Tags: blockchain.info, api, server, port

I've installed [Blockchain.info](https://www.blockchain.com) local machine on a server and got an API key for it. But it seems it's designed to work only locally and on the port `3000`.
I need to call APIs from another server with a certain IP. Unfortunately, I could not find anything about how to access to BlockChain.info machine and its APIs by calling a server IP instead of `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, and how to change the default port `3000` to something else.
May you help me please?

Comment: I suspect you have misunderstood what you are installing. Blockchain.info is not open source and there is no ability to run their software on your local machine.

Comment: @Anonymous: https://github.com/blockchain/service-my-wallet-v3

Comment: That’s not their website or service, that’s a proxy to their API.

Comment: What I need is using their API to built our own applications and website. May you guide me how can I do it using their services please or give me a link to a tutorial?